# Perl script: analyse table items occurrence and return result in a new column (something similar to a vlookup function in excel)

Tags: perl

The if statement is having the condition `$item2 eq $itemto || $item eq $itemto` and returning 1 if true, 0 otherwise. But the problem is it is analyzing one by one element in table 2. This is not my goal. What I want to do is compare each row of table 1, in which one has the 2 items (`$item` and `$item`) and search for corresponding item in the entire table 2 to see if condition is true eq 1, otherwise 0. 
Perl script:

```
foreach my $itemto (@itemsto){
   if (grep {$item2 eq $itemto || $item eq $itemto} @itemsto) {
      $turncong = 1;
      $insert_turncong->execute($mn, $yr, $item, $item2, $turncong);}
   else {
      $turncong = 0;
   }
}
```

Table 1)

```
  item   | item2  | value  | mn |  yr  | mn_yr  |  item_mn_yr     |  item2_mn_yr  
-------- +--------+--------+----+------+--------+---------------  +---------------
 Green   | Marble  | 140181 |  1 | 1998 | 1-1998 | Green-1-1998   | Marble-1-1998
 Green   | Tomato  | 162785 |  1 | 1998 | 1-1998 | Green-1-1998   | Tomato-1-1998
 Lime    | Marble  |  89307 |  1 | 1998 | 1-1998 | Lime-1-1998    | Marble-1-1998
 Lime    | Green   | 129488 |  1 | 1998 | 1-1998 | Lime-1-1998    | Green-1-1998
 Marble  | Green   | 140181 |  1 | 1998 | 1-1998 | Marble-1-1998  | Green-1-1998
 Marble  | Marble  |  77225 |  1 | 1998 | 1-1998 | Marble-1-1998  | Marble-1-1998
 Tomato  | Lime    | 104345 |  1 | 1998 | 1-1998 | Tomato-1-1998  | Lime-1-1998
 Tomato  | Green   | 162785 |  1 | 1998 | 1-1998 | Tomato-1-1998  | Green-1-1998
```

Table 2)   @itemsto

```
  item  |  yr  | mn |  item_mn_yr  
 -------+------+----+--------------
 Green  | 1998 |  1 | Green-1-1998
 Tomato | 1998 |  1 | Tomato-1-1998
```

The issue is with this current scenario is: table 1 has 1000 rows, table 2 has 15 rows, the result table is a 15000 rows.

The ideal is table 1 I has 1000 rows, the only thing I want to do is add a new column with the result 0 or 1, and the new resultant table will have a new column and still 1000 rows.

Comment: maybe try formatting next time, questions that are formatted poorly rarely get quality answers.

Comment: Is what you are trying to do something like an excel vlookup?

Comment: (1) It seems to me SQL would be more suited to this task than Perl. (2) What is the expected output for the tables you gave (3) Is the `item` in the second table guaranteed unique?

Comment: qwwqwwq in summary yes it is like vlookup ...

Comment: Hi amon, 1) Maybe yes a SQL would be more suitable 2) the expected output as described is: The ideal is a mix of: table 1 has 1000 rows, the only thing I want to do is add a new column with the result 0 or 1, and the new resultant table will have a new column and still 1000 rows. 3 ) yes the $itemto = item_mn_yr (the variable of table 2) is an unique id.

Comment: Ok. Now this `$insert_turncong->execute(...)` – what does it do? What module are you using? What is the class of this object? How can you *update* instead of *inserting*? Of course I could write a text-based solution that emits a text file with an extra column, but this doesn't seem sensible.

Comment: Hi Amon, the intention of insert_turncong is to alocate the variables values obtained after each foreach loop. The module being used is Config:General. This object is a table in which the line will be inserted. Update instead of inserting, I am not sure about it. Thanks,